# Is there is a way to hide application network calls from network intercept

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

When someone run my android app on emulator and they open network intercept. All my app networks calls are shown (The API urls). I want to disable/ hide this. I'm using okhttp and disabled the log interceptor. But still shows these data.

Comment: why would you want to do that lol

Comment: @Rainb I was just wondering. But nothing is important about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing something pretty sketchy. You'll want to obfuscate your application with ProGuard or DexGuard and potentially use a port other than 443 for your TLS traffic.

Comment: Thank you. Not something important. I was just wondering if there is a way for something like that.